# Execute callback in a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using an API for a camera that returns the image via callback, like this:

```
camera.StartCapture(ImageEvent);

protected void ImageEvent(ManagedImage image)
{
    // do something with the image
}
```

The problem is that `ImageEvent` keeps being called, not letting other methods run properly. So I want to run `ImageEvent` in a different thread, how do I do this?

A solution using async/await would be preferable.

Comment: You could run `StartCapture` in a different thread. Is this `ManagedImage` related to the UI in any way? If so, you'll get some multithreading access issues.

Comment: @Stefan, so if I pass the delegate from a new thread, the delegated method will run in this new thread? Also, it is not UI related.

Comment: Can you explain your `not letting other methods run properly` issue a bit more? If you don't show the images, do you process them and write them to disk? Have you checked your harddisk's activity?

Comment: You might also be able to make use of `await/async` but then you'll need async operations in your handlers. You should properly show some more code for that.

Comment: @Stefan The "not letting other methods run properly" was a weird bug where the callback kept being called like a infinite loop and the other methods were not executing. I restarted my computer and the camera and now it works properly, without the need of a new thread. Thank you for your attention! Should I delete my question?

Comment: Yes, I think that's appropriate. Keep in mind though, that "weird bugs" are very rare. You might want to check if al your clean-up routines are in place. Although it's managed, proper disposure, especially with imaging objects, is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
camera.StartCapture(image => Task.Run(() => ImageEvent(image)));
```

Comment: But ImageEvent would still run in the main thread. I want to avoid it being called in the main thread at all.

Comment: @GabrielJ sure, put it outside ImageEvent, let me edit

Comment: It turns out to be a little more complicated than that because `camera` is of dynamic type. But I won't end up using multithreading anyway. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time